# ATK not running out of the box

Tags: php, redhat, atk4, agiletoolkit

I'm very new to all this so please be gentle with me. I've been teaching myself PHP and decided to check out some application frameworks and decided Agile Toolkit seemed to offer some of the best features. However, having unzipped the install file into my web root I can't get it working. I get 'HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error)' when I try to access the Agile Dashboard.

I am running Apache 2 on RHEL5 (64-bit) with PHP 5.2.17. All other software I have is running fine so I am at a bit of a loss as to why ATK4 isn't. I've checked the config.php and from the httpd logs it appears to be using the correct path when trying to load. I did edit loader.php  by commenting out the existing code and uncommenting the alternative code to see if that made any difference and I did get 'Low level error: Class is not defined and couldn't be loaded: Frontend'.

I've tried the examples and the html page loads, but the examples fail too. When the MySQL settings are wrong the error reports this, but when the MySQL settings are correct I get the 500 error or the low level error, depending on what is set in the config file.

Can anyone give me some pointers as to why this isn't working? Or where I can look to get more information or logs that I should be looking at? Are there settings I am unaware of?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Curious issue. Can you look into apache's error_log or PHP log to see what produces the 500 error? Obviously the 500 errors blocks the normal functionality of Agile Toolkit, when you change files you introduce new errors but that does not solve the 500 error. Try opening atk4/lib/ApiWeb.php and placing `exit` in the body of main() function. See also: http://agiletoolkit.org/blog/how-to-solve-error-in-my-program/

Comment: This also might be helpful: http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/understand/api/exec

Comment: Hi Roman. Thanks for your prompt reply. Sorry for the delay in responding. The only error I am seeing in the php_error_log is: Call to undefined function json_encode() in /var/www/html/agiletoolkit/atk4/lib/jQuery/Chain.php on line 163. I can't find any other errors being generated.

Comment: It's a standard functions since PHP. 5.2 Can you double-check the PHP version? Try upgrading to PHP5.3 if you continue having the internal error. If it's in fact a problem with Agile Toloolkit, I'd love to get it fixed by the next release.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Roman I have now got Agile Toolkit working. I feel slightly foolish, but I'm learning every day.

The problem was that the version of PHP I am using has json disabled. Once I realised that I uncommented it from the json.ini file I found and that enabled it.

Now I can get on with the serious business of learning this stuff :).

Thanks again!

Comment: is it disabled by default on redhat?